# Web Database Application Generator

Tags: sql, database, generator, backend

Do you know some web application that generates code for a backend to manage a database like Caspio?

Answer (score 1):

I use [phprunner](http://xlinesoft.com/phprunner/index.htm). If you need an open source / free software use: `dadabik` (simple and easy), or `xataface`. Both use php and support mysql database.